# In the derivative of squared error the result of matrix-vector squared is not clear

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I do not understand the rules of squared matrix vector multiplication in the following example:
[image]

e.g when I do not understand how we get the last term for Eq 6. We have XwXw, how does it turn into wXXY?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$,

$$(Y-Xw)^T(Y-Xw)=(Y^T-w^TX^T)(Y-Xw)=Y^TY-Y^TXw-w^TX^TY+w^TX^TXw$$

Comment: is it also true that $(Z - AB)^T = -(AB)^T + Z^T$ coz $(AB)^T$ only talks about multiplication

Comment: We have $-(AB)^T+Z^T=-B^TA^T+Z^T$, don't forget the braces.